# How to combine three small perl programs as one?

Tags: perl

I wrote three small programs in perl.
I have Program1.pl, then Program2.pl (which uses output generated by Program1.pl as input) and then I have Program3.pl (which uses output generated by Program2.pl as input).

Now I want to write a program which 'calls' all three programs, so that the user only has to run one program, namely MainProgram.pl.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Without knowing the actual code, it's obviously difficult to answer.

Comment: You could put the three calls in a shell script or Batch-file (on Windows).

Comment: From a design perspective, is there some reason that you don't actually merge these programs into one actual program or perhaps convert the programs to modules and run from a single script? This would be the normal way of "combining", unless you have a reason not to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I depends on what do you mean with *combine*, but if you can do this, for example, creating a pipe:

```
open(PIPE, "perl Program1.pl | perl Program2.pl | perl Prograp3.pl |") or die "can't create pipe: $!";
while(<PIPE>){
  print;
}
```

Comment: I don't really know if 'combine' is the correct word, but I want to run all three programs by just running one program.. Does that make any sense..?

Comment: yes of course. But you programs must be ready to work in a pipe. You can't just combine any programs you want. You say "which uses output generated by Program1.pl as input". That sounds like a good task for a pipe. But if you could provide some examples, it would be easier to help you

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try and explain it with examples:
Program1 takes input from a two column txt file. The file is placed into a hash, with keys as column1 and values as column2. Then another txt file is read into another hash - same format as the first one.

Now, if there are corresponding entries in the hashes, those are written to Output1.txt. If no matches are found, the keys and values are written to Output2.txt, seperated by a tab.

Comment: Program2 takes Output2.txt as input, again read into a hash like the previous two times. The keys and values are then compared. If they are 100% identical, they are written to Output3.txt. If not, the keys and values are written to Output4.txt, seperated by a tab.

Program3 takes Output4.txt as input. The inputfile is read into an array. A for-loop goes trough the array, and matching each element to various regular expressions. If a match is found, the array element is written to Output5.txt and if a match is not found, the array element is written to Output6.txt

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: I think you can use pipes in this scenario

Comment: how would the code for the pipe look?
Something like this, maybe?
`code`open (PIPE, "|perl Script.FalseFriends.1.0.5.IW.2012-06-18.pl | Script.IdenticalCognates.1.0.6.IW.2012-06-21.pl | Script.RegexRules.1.0.7.IW.2012-06-27.pl|");`code`

`code`while(<PIPE>)
{ 
  print; 
}`code`

Comment: but remove `|` at the end of the string: `open (PIPE, "perl...`

Comment: if the scripts are reading into files Output[n].txt in "hard" so you can call the three scripts in a sequence this can be done in perl with "system" function

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a bit of a design problem here; it would make sense to be passing data from sub to sub, or be using an OO structure, rather than piping one script into another then into another

Answer (score 0):

Unless the "Output[n]" files are needed by a human, you simply need to push your results into arrays, then read the arrays into hashes on subsequent steps. This only works for cases where the number of items will fit into memory. If you are processing gigabytes of data, you might need the intermediary files.

push is an array operator.

Pipes cannot be readily used because you have more than one output, and more than one condition on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you want to change your code it could be very simple, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system('perl Program1.pl');
system('perl Program2.pl');
system('perl Program3.pl');
```

Or you could rewrite your scripts into a single script with subroutines for each part you want to execute.  Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

part_A();
part_B();
part_C();
exit;

sub part_A {
    # code from Program1.pl goes in here
}

sub part_B {
    # code from Program2.pl goes here
}

sub part_C {
    # code from Program3.pl here
}
```

But honestly, it sounds like you just need to write a new script that does all the logic you need, and just git rid of the other scripts.  It would be simpler to not write all those "temp" files just to read them in again to continue processing.  You can pass hashes and arrays into subroutines and have them return hashes or arrays, or just have them modify the ones you passed in (if you pass in references).

Oh, and the mention of using pipes- pipes are only useful when taking standard out and/or standard error of one program and sending that to standard in to another program.  And since you said that your scripts write to files and read from files, then they are not printing to standard out nor reading from standard in.  Thus piping them together won't benefit you any more than just calling each one in sequence.  You could just as well execute them in on line like this (from bash shell):

```
$ Program1.pl && Program2.pl && Program3.pl
```